# html5 listener loadeddata do not work certain

Tags: javascript, html

I' am desperated.
Why this works:

```
var myVid=document.getElementById("movie");
myVid.onloadeddata=console.log("Browser has loaded the current frame");
```

and this do not:

```
myVid.addEventListener("loadeddata", function()  {
  alert("loadeddata");
  });
```

tried both in firefox 27.

her my page where it shout run: 
[www.x.opteynde.com](http://www.x.opteynde.com)

My target is to get the loading-time of the video.

Answer (score 10):

After two days searching  I found the solution.
To fire the events there has to be a video.load() before.
The loop and the autoplay-tags in the html-video-markup aren't enough.

Comment: try `$('#movie').load(function(e) { /* do work */ });`

Answer (score 8):

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("movie");
myVid.onloadeddata = console.log("Browser has loaded the current frame");
```

This doesn't do what you expect. You're not binding a function to `myVid.onloadeddata`, you're immediatly executing `console.log()`, and setting the return value of that to `myVid.onloadeddata`.

The proper way to do this, is:

```
myVid.onloadeddata = function() {
    console.log("Browser has loaded the current frame");
}
```

So this would explain why this would output something in your console.

On to `loadeddata`:

The [definition of `loadeddata`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video) is:

> The user agent can render the media data at the current playback position for the first 
>   time.

In slightly less formal speak, this means: *"The user agent can render at least one frame of actual video"*.

In my Firefox error console I see these errors:

```
Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource fliege.mp4 failed.
HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource http://www.x.opteynde.com/fliege.ogv failed.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

Obviously, Firefox can't render a frame from a video it can't load, so this 404 seems to be  your problem.

P.S.
Also note that in [this example](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) `loadeddata` isn't fired until you click the 'play' button.

Comment: Yeah that's why I made sure to mention your answer. I was just extending. Gj btw

Comment: sorry thats not my question. I know how to add a function like myVid.onloadeddata ...
This works well: myVid.onloadeddata = console.log("Browser has loaded the current frame");
The question is: why the addEventListener do not work.

Comment: @hamburger Well, the code you posted wasn't correct, and (together with the 404) quite probably the source of your confusion.

Comment: ok there is a missing ogg file. but it renders the mp4 one. so it shout add a listener. also the error listener do not work.
I updated my code on the side that you can see that all listeners do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've got kind the same issue here and the problem was that i registered the event listener inside body.onload event.

```
window.onload = function() {
            myVideo.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            alert('loadeddata');

        });
}
```

When window.onload event is triggered, myVideo.loadeddata already have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Great explination by [Carpetsmoker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911459/html5-listener-loadeddata-do-not-work-certain#21957528).

However, my question is, you have it tagged as jQuery, why not use jQuery?

So i'm just adding to his answer a little with some jQuery tips.

In jQuery you can use CSS selectors to easily get an element. For instance, you're element with the ID `movie` is as easy to get as:

```
var myVid = $('#movie');
```

From there you can make use of it with ease.

I'm not familiar with what you're doing, but generally assigning an event in jQuery is as easy as:

```
$('#movie').on('event', function(e) { /* do work */ });
```

That said, i'm not 100% sure `$('#movie').on('loadeddata '` will actually work. I havn't played with media much, but I do know you might also look at jQuery's [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Last but not least, if you need to use the actual element in vanilla JS, just simply do something like:

```
var myVid = $('#movie')[0]; // much easier to read and reuse than .getElementByID
// however take note, this is more JS to run thus causing a a lil less speed
myVid.onloaddata = function() { /* do work */ };
```

Comment: Yeah, jQuery would obviously be better. Didn't want to ramble on *too* long in my answer though ;-) And `.on('loadeddata'` will just work as expected.

Comment: $('#movie').on('loadstart', function(e) {     console.log("_onloadstart third execution");     });

also do not work